# How trigger will fire on multiple rows insert in single transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I created a `FOR INSERT` trigger that will fire after inserting. Below are the different scenarios for which I would like to know how trigger will fire.

The trigger is on an `employee` table.
I begin one transaction where I insert 4 rows. My doubt is how trigger will fire.

1. Will it fire immediately after inserting each row?
2. Will it fire after completion of all the rows in that transaction

We are able to access the `inserted` & `deleted` special tables from the trigger.

1. How many rows will be present in those tables each time? Only one record? Or multiple records?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without seeing how you're performing the insert of 4 rows, it's not possible to say what the trigger will see. Is this 4 separate insert statements, or one insert statement inserting all 4 rows?

Comment: I want to know in both scenarios.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trigger will fire after each `INSERT` statement.

If you have 4 `INSERT` statements, each of 1 row, the trigger will be fired 4 times with 1 record in the `inserted` special table after each insert.

If you have 1 `INSERT` statement of 4 rows, the trigger will be fired just 1 time with 4 records in the `inserted` special table after the insert.

If they are transactional inserts, the actions you perform in the trigger will be transactional too. This is very important if the trigger has an internal transaction.